# Rendering Tiles by Maperitive while routing with Graphhopper

Tags: openstreetmap, graphhopper

im new to these softwares and am stuck in a project im working on. My goal is to use modified OSM files and implement a navigation/routing to travel through my custom roads. I have tried graphhopper web and the routing works, but the tiles/map have not changed, it is as if im travelling through invisible roads.
Is there a way to replace it with png tiles created from Maperitive?
A step-by-step guide would be very helpful.

Comment: As already explained in your previous question, routing and rendering usually use different databases. If you want to use local tiles from Maperitive then just configure your tile source in Leaflet or OpenLayers accordingly

Comment: There will be a new GraphHopper feature in 0.13 (release will be Sept 2019) that gives you basic tiles for debugging so that you do not travel through invisible roads ;) https://github.com/graphhopper/graphhopper/pull/1572